# Compatibility to BB86

Tags: bottom-bracket

I have a second hand frame circa 2014 that measures about 74mm across at BB.

I'm fitting an Ultegra crankset.

Shimano states I need a BB94-41 for a shell width of 86mm ?????

Am I reading this wrong? how can a BB86 fit in a frame width of 74mm.

Im confused

Comment: I don't know the specific numbers, but most BB setups are "adjustable" to some degree, since the cup on at least one side can be screwed in (or not) by a variable amount.  I would guess the adjustability amounts to 5-10mm total.

Comment: its a press fit BB

Comment: A photo of the BB shell will help here. Which Ultegra version crank do you have and where did you find the information on what BB you need?

Comment: its an FC 6800 CRANK

Comment: I looked up which bb I needed from shimano produce data specs.

Comment: whats confusing me is the mention of numbers, what do they mean, are they relevant or just random spec reference.

Comment: does a BB86 or its latest equivalent fit in a 74mm wife frame.

Comment: Do you have a link for the spec sheet?

Comment: There is a Shimano BB94 BB but it's in the XTR range https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/xtr-m9000/SM-BB94-41A.html

Comment: http://productinfo.shimano.com/#/spec/2.0/ROAD/Front%20Chainwheel

Answer (score 1):

You have the 73mm version of either BB30 or PF30. Running a Shimano road crank will be physically impossible because the spindle isn't long enough.

Answer (score 0):

The spec sheet you provided a link to says the recommended BB for a FC-6800 crank  is a Shimano SM-BB72-41B. I believe that BB is a BB86 type for a 86.5mm wide press fit shell ([see here](https://www.artscyclery.com/Shimano_SM-BB72_Press_Fit_Bottom_Bracket_Road-41B/descpage-SHBB7241B.html)).

If you have a press fit frame that measures 74mm at the shell I think that would be a BB30 or PF30  which both have 68 and 73mm versions.

I think what you will need is a BB30/PF30 to BB86 adapter. I haven't googled to see it such a thing exists but it seems possible because BB86 has a 24mm spindle whereas BB30 has 30mm.